# How to connect to Mongolab from Flask MongoEngine on Heroku?

Tags: python, mongodb, heroku, flask, mongoengine

I've got a website built in the Python [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) framework which I now want to deploy to [Heroku](http://heroku.com/). In my website I use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) with the [MongoEngine ORM](http://mongoengine.org/). In my config.py file I've currently got mongoDB defined as follows:

```
MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
    'db': 'mymongodb'
}
```

In my `__init__.py` I then load the config file:

```
app.config.from_object('config')
mongoDb = MongoEngine(app)
```

This works when running the DB locally on my laptop. So as suggested [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#getting-your-connection-uri) I run  `heroku config | grep MONGOLAB_URI` to get the uri. As [suggested here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html) I then tried pasting that uri in the current code (I x-ed the username and password away):

```
MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
    'host': 'mongodb://heroku_appxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@ds0123456.mongolab.com:12345/heroku_appxxxxx'
}
```

After committing and pushing to heroku I still get an Application Error though. My logs give a `TypeError: connect() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)` (for full stacktrace see below). So I presume MongoEngine doesn't read the host from the MONGODB_SETTINGS, but I wouldn't know how else to do it. I checked out [the official Python example for MongoLab](https://github.com/mongolab/mongodb-driver-examples/blob/master/python/pymongo_simple_example.py) which works with PyMongo, but it doesn't help me any further.

Does anybody know how I can connect to Mongolab from MongoEngine? All tips are welcome!

```
2014-12-09T15:18:17.157377+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467335+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-12-09 15:18:17 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467341+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467343+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467345+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467347+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467348+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467350+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467352+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467373+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467375+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467376+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467378+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467379+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467381+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467382+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467384+00:00 app[web.1]:     mongoDb = MongoEngine(app)  # Load document store (mongodb)
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467385+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mongoengine/__init__.py", line 33, in __init__
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467387+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.init_app(app)
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467388+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mongoengine/__init__.py", line 66, in init_app
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467389+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.connection = mongoengine.connect(**conn_settings)
2014-12-09T15:18:17.467391+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: connect() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer; I need to also list the database name. So the following nailed it:

```
MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
    'db': 'heroku_appxxxxx',
    'host': 'mongodb://heroku_appxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@ds0123456.mongolab.com:12345/heroku_appxxxxx'
}
```